# making a image reader that will check the black squares on the paper and give an out by the postion of each black squre and give a out put

Tags: python, image-processing

so i been trying to make it that works on website anyways
i have been studiing the way of and since its my first time i have zero clue what to do so i would like a help how to do it
example :
you give it a photo a paper -> then there is something like qr code scaner like this this :

```
■                                                ■

■                                                ■

■                                                ■

■                                                ■
■                                                ■
■                                                ■
■                                                ■
```

and then give a out put by each place of black dots

Comment: Check the findContours function in OpenCV.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.